# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'db'. while pushing object in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to push an object using firebase, where angular will act as frontend.
**component.html**

```
<h3>Adding an object</h3>
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="addCourse(course)" #course>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FirebaseDemo';
  // courses: any[];

  courses$;
  course$;
  author$;
  todos$: AngularFireList<any>;
  // subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    // code to read the courses.
    db.list('/course')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((inp) => {
        this.courses$ = inp;
        console.log(this.courses$);
      });
  }
  addCourse(value: string) {
    db.list('/course/').set('4', value);
  }
}
```

Here the last instance of db in addCourse(value) function is throwing error called **cannot find name db.**
How can I access db variable out of constructor or How can I push the object in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of constructor, you can access db by using this.db. Please try the below change in you addCourse function and verify..

```
addCourse(value: string) {
this.db.list('/course/').set('4', value);}
```

Also make changes to constructor to make db public/private like:

```
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase)
```

Comment: Already tried it, didn't work. this.varname works when we declare a property in angular.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. I think making the db public or private in constructor and then adding this.db in addCourse(val) will work.. Please verify it